# Overlay Graph3D with Graphics, with aligned coordinates

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, graphics3d, combinatorics, lattices

I have a Graph3D object representing a 3D lattice path

```
g3d = With[{n = 4}, 
   Graph3D[GridGraph[{n, n, n}], 
    VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range[n], 3]]];
g1 = HighlightGraph[g3d, Subgraph[g3d, FindPath[g3d, 1, 64, {9}, 1]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

and a Graphics3D object of selected cubes beneath it

```
PlanePartitionDiagram[l_List] := 
 Module[{i, j, k}, 
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.01]}], 
    Table[Cuboid[{j, -i, k}], {i, Length[l]}, {j, Length[l[[i]]]}, {k,
       l[[i, j]]}]}, Boxed -> False, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic",
    ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
      RGBColor[1., 0.96, 
       0.2], {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}}, {"Directional", 
      RGBColor[0.2, 0.2, 1.], {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}, {"Directional",
       RGBColor[1., 0.2, 0.2], {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}}]]
pp1 = PlanePartitionDiagram[{{0, 3, 2, 2}, {0, 3, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 
    2}, {0, 0, 0, 2}}]
```

[image]

getting after `Show[{pp1, g1}]`

[image]

What I can't do is get the lattice path graph and the plane partition to align so that the bottom left corner of each image are aligned, and the cubes are beneath the path, similar to:

[image]

It appears the viewpoint on the two figures with `Show` has to be shared. Is there a way of aligning them?

Comment: I think there is a minor problem with the parentheses, but I can't see where.

Comment: should be `Show[pp1, MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, TranslationTransform[{0, -5, -1}]] &, Show[g1], {1}]]`

Comment: Yes that works well. I also adjusted the plane partition to `PlanePartitionDiagram[{{0, 3, 2, 2}, {0, 3, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 2}}]`, and the lattice path to `{49, 50, 51, 35, 19, 23, 24, 8, 12, 16}`, and used `Show[pp1, 
 MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, TranslationTransform[{1, -4, 0}]] &,
   Show[g1], {1}]]` to get a fitting example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `TranslationTransform` to move the origin of the graph object:

```
ClearAll[tr]
tr[g_, pp_] := MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, 
    TranslationTransform[
     First[Transpose @ CoordinateBounds[Cases[pp, Cuboid[x_] :> x, All]]] - 
      First[Transpose @ CoordinateBounds@GraphEmbedding[g]]]] &, 
  Show @ g, {1}]
```

***Examples:***

```
nng = IndexGraph@NearestNeighborGraph[#, VertexCoordinates -> #] & @ Tuples[Range[4], 3];

pp1 = PlanePartitionDiagram[{{0, 3, 2, 2}, {0, 3, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 2}}];

g1 = HighlightGraph[nng, Subgraph[nng, FindPath[nng, 1, 64, {9}, 1]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"];

Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {g1, pp1}]
```

[image]

```
Show[pp1, tr[g1, pp1]]
```

[image]

```
pp2 = PlanePartitionDiagram[{{0, 3, 2, 2}, {0, 3, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 2}}];

g2 = HighlightGraph[nng, Subgraph[nng, {49, 50, 51, 35, 19, 23, 24, 8, 12, 16}], 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"];

Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {g2, pp2}]
```

[image]

```
Show[pp2, tr[g2, pp2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the definition of `g3d`,but I don't know how to change the `HighlightGraph` :-(

```
newg3d[x_, y_, z_] := 
  With[{n = 5}, 
   Graph3D[GridGraph[{n, n, n}], 
    VertexCoordinates -> 
     Tuples[{Range[5] + x, Range[5] + y, Range[5] + z}]]];
g3d = newg3d[0, -5, 0];
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think this works, I just need to adjust where the lattice path starts and finishes.